# node-virtualcam npm module on windows 10 is not working

Tags: node.js, windows-10, node-modules, directshow, virtual-webcam

I want to try [node-virtualcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-virtualcam) available on https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-virtualcam
I am on Windows 10, 64 bit

so I followed following steps to try.

1. run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015` with admin `cmd`
2. `git clone https://github.com/letmaik/node-virtualcam`
3. `cd node-virtualcam`
4. `npm install`
5. Downloaded https://github.com/Fenrirthviti/obs-virtual-cam/releases/download/2.0.5/OBS-Virtualcam-2.0.5-Windows.zip
6. After doing unzip I run `regsvr32 /n /i:1 ".\OBS-Virtualcam-2.0.5-Windows\bin\32bit\obs-virtualsource.dll"`
7. I saw successful installed message in cmd
8. `node samples\sample.js`
9. Seeing message on cmd "virtual cam output started (1280x720 @ 30fps)"

But I am not seeing virtual webcam on google meet in video settings nor in VLC capture devices. How can I check and see if virtual webcam and this module is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see newly registered virtual camera using 32 bit [graphEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit) in `Video Capture Sources`

[image]